# DDD - Injecting a ConfigurationService into an Entity

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

In my domain model I have an Entity called 'Inventory'. To make a certain move in inventory I need to access business level configuration to check.

I have following methods in the Inventory Entity

```
public class Inventory
{
  // Some codes, properties and arguments are omitted for brevity.
  public int InventoryId { get; set; }
  public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<InventoryTransaction> Transactions { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Stock> Stocks {get; set; }
  // ........

  public void purchase(double qty, decimal cost) { //....... }
  public double QuantitiesOnHand() { //..... }
  public decimal CostOfItemsOnHand() { //....... }

  // This method require to access certain configuration in order to 
  // process the sale of item.
  public decimal Sell(double qty, decimal cost) { //..... }
}
```

To process the sales I need to access certain configuration. Is it good practice to inject a configuration interface in order to process sale within this entity. Will it damage the purity of DDD? Or should I move only this 'Sell()' method to a Domain service layer?

**EDIT :**

`public virtual IList<Stock> Stocks {get; set; }` was added to the above class definition which holds the stock for the particular inventory item.

Comment: why not pass the configuration value to the sell method?

Comment: DomainService for simplicity or refactor it when it does harm.

Comment: @DavinTryon, Your are right. but I have around 3 to 4 settings which I need to pass. Also I have doubt in future it might increase. Please tell your suggestion.

Comment: Pass the configuration service to the sell method.

Comment: @eulerfx do you think this is a good practice for a domain-driven-design?

Comment: Yes it is acceptable to pass to method, injecting into entity constructor will violate SRP for other use cases and complicate construction.

Comment: @eulerfx. sounds good, and will it be ok if I make the costing policies as strategy pattern and inject it to the method? or should it be taken out from the entity and moved to domain service if it contains injection of ICostingStrategy? suggestion please.

Comment: You can pass any type of domain service to a method on an entity if it is required for the behavior implemented by the method. If you shift this to a domain service or app service all you're doing is moving business logic away from the entity.

Comment: @eulerfx understand. Thx

Answer (score 3):

Sell/purchase operations doesn't look like they belong to this entity. I mean, those operations could be (and probably are) much more then just decrement/increment quantity. Also, their responsibility probably spans multiple entities.

These methods are good candidates for some kind of domain service. E.g.:

```
public class InventoryTradeService
{
  public void purchase(Inventory inventory, double quantity)
  public void sell(Inventory inventory, double quantity)
}
```

Regarding your "ConfigurationService", if it is "business level configuration" as you said, it should be part of domain model. So, there is no reason to inject it - just access it. If it is not part of the model, think about incorporating it.

Comment: Actually in my design, Inventory is a single entity that is responsible for handling inventory of a single product. So the purchase / selling of a single product will be listed in the IList<InventoryTransaction> Transactions list and IList<Stock> Stocks list of the entity. In that case I think we do not need a seperate service for this. suggest.

Comment: I'm a bit worried `Inventory` as an aggregate root, containing an `IList<InventoryTransaction` and `IList<Stock>` might grow too large. Any idea how many transactions and stocks you plan on storing?

Comment: @BlueBird can you please describe you're business level configuration, what kind of stuff are inside?

Comment: @JefClaes, IList<InventoryTransaction> can grow to maximum as possible as trasactions happens. But the IList<Stock> will be limited as it depicts the real stock in hand that is ready for resale. Any suggestions please..

Comment: @gseric, I have some configuration like, "Allow negative balance", "Costing method" and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't digest your configuration service. It smells terribly to me:) It's not a question how to inject it but if there is a better way to implement it's behavior...
ATM it's behavior is similar to Service Locator/Registry (anti)pattern.

Comment: To be more specific:
You didn't specified if those settings are configurable by end users - I assume they are. If that's the case I would leave it to application layer to use your domain in configured way. This way your domain would support all configurable operations but wouldn't deal with configuration.